# @ManagedProperty does not reflect changes and keeps returning null

Tags: jsf, null, managed-property

I'm trying to inject the value of one sessionscoped bean into a viewscoped bean but it keeps returning null, here's a snippet:

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

//Class for managing the current logged-in user
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable{

private String userName;

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}
```

And it's used in:

```
@ManagedBean(name="databrowser")
@ViewScoped
public class dataBrowser implements Serializable {  

private List<UploadData> dataItems;
private SelectItem[] dataTypeOptions, qualityOptions, accessOptions;
private UploadData selectedData;
private String filelocation;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{user.userName}")
private String userName;

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}
```

dataBrowser is used to populate a Primefaces datatable, when it's called userName is null and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Do you have a setter for `userName`? You need one in order to make injection work.

Comment: ... you need a setter in the @ViewScoped bean as well.

Comment: That would have thrown an exception rather than returning `null`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, easter weekend - yes sorry I do have this directly after the getter code: public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}

Comment: Maybe some more information would help - I also have a second ViewScoped bean that injects user.userName - the code for this is identical to the @ManagedProperty injection code in databrowser. This second bean is initialised and used/accessed in a function inside databrowser.

Comment: solved it -> ended up moving my functions around and using @PostConstruct to make sure injection preceeded use of the variables

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have problem with injecting nested managed bean properties by `@ManagedProperties` too. Once injected it never changed. I did a workaround by evaluating EL in getter instead of injecting it.

Try that:

```
public String getUserName() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (String) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context,"#{user.userName}", String.class);
}
```

You can also try injecting entire `user` bean and get `userName` field from it in getter.

Answer (score 0):

With all setters/getters in place, I was having the same problem (**null** reference to user) because of **missing empty constructor in User class**.

In the example you provided, the `dataBrowser` and user beans are instantiated before constructing the table, so referencing `#{dataBrowser.userName}` should already find the `userName @ManagedProperty` correctly injected (not being a `@PostConstruct` problem).

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem, and found out by chance, that it is not working, if I try with firefox (actually icedove under linux), but well working, if I try with the eclipse build-in browser.

Even so this does not make sense to me, have you tried with different browsers already?

---

michal777's answer is very well working. I have extended it to this:

```
    @ManagedProperty("#{nameBean}")
private NameBean nameBean;  
public NameBean getNameBean() { return nameBean; }
public void setNameBean(NameBean nameBean) { this.nameBean = nameBean; }

public NameBean getNameBean_Workaround() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (NameBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context,"#{nameBean}", NameBean.class);
}
```

and later on:

```
    if (nameBean != null) {
        nameBean.setName("achsooo");
    }
    else {
        getNameBean_Workaround().setName("achsooo2222");
    }
```

Now, in the eclipse browser "achsooo" gets set, and in icedove "achsooo2222" gets set.

Answer (score 0):

`#{user.userName}` is interpreted by JSF as `getUser().getUserName()`

So it is better to have a `@ManagedProperty` of type `User`, with its getter/setter methods `getUser`/`setUser`. With that you can access the user's name by `#{user.userName}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the problem was actually twofold. (Note also that @ManagedProperty will only ever work in a @ManagedBean class and if that @ManagedProperty class is of the same or lesser scope (application, session, view, request, etc.).) Here is how I fixed it:

---

**Problem 1:** JSF is stupid and doesn't handle `@ManagedProperty` injection properly in `abstract` classes.

**Solution:**

1. Make every class that uses `@ManagedProperty` be annotated with `@ManagedBean`.
2. Make every `abstract` class that uses the property not be annotated with `@ManagedProperty` and instead only provide abstract getter and setter methods that non-abstract classes will each override.
3. Use the `abstract` class's getter method instead of the @ManagedProperty itself in `abstract` classes.

---

**Problem 2:** JSF is stupid and doesn't handle `@ManagedProperty` injection properly in @ManagedBean classes not created by JSF (i.e. you are creating these classes yourself using `new`).

**Solution options:**

- Let JSF create the class that uses the `@ManagedProperty`.
- Use the following code:

---

```
MyClass example = Utils.getELValue("EL Expression Goes Here", MyClass.class);

public static <T> T getELValue(final String elName, final Class<T> clazz) {
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  return (T) fc.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(fc.getELContext(), null, elName);

  // Potential (untested) alternative:
  // ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession().getAttribute("")
}
```